# 404 redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want to set up a rule in my .htaccess file so that any url that is enetered, that results in a 404 because there is no such file, automatically re-directs to the home page of the site:
index.php

my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^queenslandbeerweek.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://queenslandbeerweek.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

This causes the index.php file to show but is broken and leaves the eroneous URL in the address bar.

I have read in the answer to another post that it has something to do with passing the erroneous URL as a parameter, causing the page to not load properly, because the page calls data from a database and it is passing the bad URL as a parameter of index.php but there was no hint as to what the solution is.

What I would like to happen, is if an incorrect URL is typed into the address bar, or if a link is followed, to a file that does not exist, the completely forget about this file, drop everything, and go to the home page index.php.

index.php calls data from a database

Is this possible using a .htaccess file?

I have exactly the same problem with another of my sites.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers, Al.

Comment: Side note: It is recommended for SEO purposes and for usability to have a 404 page and not to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can directly redirect an error document but you can catch nonexistent files and folders

`!-f` means not a file `!-d` means not a directory, `$1` is whatever is in `(.*)` (the path in the url)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?errorurl=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks to Patrick for helping me in the chat window. I have used the above without the ?errorurl=$1 as I didn't need to catch the erroneous URL. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

You can place the 404 error template anywhere you want. For example you could place all error messages in a folder called errormessages

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php
```

Comment: He already knows how toset the error doc as you can see hes using it in his question. What he wants is it redirected to another location, that way the url that caused the 404 isnt shown anymore. Simply setting the errordocument just has it render that document at that same 404 url.

Comment: hmmm. This has me thinking. AM I going about this the wrong way. Should I make a custom 404.php file that has nothing but  an immediate re-direct to the home page

Comment: like:   header('location: index.php'); or something?

Comment: @Almeister9 check my answer, you have to catch nonexistent files/folders